# Unable to compile simple jsoncpp program with Eclipse on LInux

Tags: c++, eclipse, jsoncpp

The File is at the location /home/shivang/Desktop and the filename is sh1.cpp
Source code for the file is given below

```
#include iostream
#include json/json.h
#include json/reader.h

using namespace std;
using namespace Json;

int main() {
    std::string example = "{\"array\":[\"item1\", \"item2\"], \"not an array\":\"asdf\"}";
    Value value;
    Reader reader;

    bool parsed = reader.parse(example, value, false);
    std::cout << parsed;

    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    return 0;
}
```

The following error messages are displayed.

```
/home/shivang/Desktop/sh1.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
/home/shivang/Desktop/sh1.cpp:10:2: error: ‘Value’ was not declared in this scope
/home/shivang/Desktop/sh1.cpp:10:8: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘value’
/home/shivang/Desktop/sh1.cpp:11:2: error: ‘Reader’ was not declared in this scope
/home/shivang/Desktop/sh1.cpp:11:9: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘reader’
/home/shivang/Desktop/sh1.cpp:13:16: error: ‘reader’ was not declared in this scope
/home/shivang/Desktop/sh1.cpp:13:38: error: ‘value’ was not declared in this scope
```

Configuration gcc version 4.5.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) 
              jsoncpp-src-0.5.0
              eclipse-cpp-helios-SR2-linux-gtk

Comment: Some Googling has shown dat dis maybe a linker problem and I have to add a shared library while compiling. /workspace/hello/src$ g++ hello.cpp -l libjson_linux-gcc-4.5.2_libmt.so -L /usr/lib/ /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibjson_linux-gcc-4.5.2_libmt.so But the file is located in the specified folder.Is this a permissions issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Json or C++ before. But a little googling around led me to [this page](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/class_json_1_1_value.html). I think adding the following line to your list of includes should help:

```
#include <json/value.h>
```

Comment: I implemented what you said but I am still getting the same errors. You sure this not a linker problem.

Comment: Some Googling has shown dat dis maybe a linker problem and I have to add a shared library while compiling.                          /workspace/hello/src$ g++ hello.cpp -l libjson_linux-gcc-4.5.2_libmt.so -L /usr/lib/
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibjson_linux-gcc-4.5.2_libmt.so   But the file is located in the specified folder.Is this a permissions issue?

Comment: Obviously one cannot tell that from here. I had assumed your project setup was fine. Can you read that "so" file? What happens when you do an `ls -l` on that file? The link I mentioned also has a step by step tutorial on how to get started. Can you make sure you followed all the steps?